# Prepend email subject prefix when send mails with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

If i send an email with Laravel like this:

```
Mail::send('folder.view', $data, function($msg)
{
    $msg->to('dest@email.com');
    $msg->subject('email subject');
});
```

I want to extend the core class **Illuminate\Mail\Message.php** of Laravel
to set a default subject prefix like this:

```
[Projectname] email subject
```

How i can extend the core class to avoid overwriting with an composer update?

Answer (score 2):

Subclass `Message` and put your code into a different namespace and file:

```
<?php

namespace my\namespace;

class MyMessage extends Illuminate\Mail\Message
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i did. My class is in app/lib/Message.php and app/lib is also autoloaded. But when i send an email my subject is still the same; without prefix. I used the posted methods from Karl Laurentius Roos. Thats exactly what i did too.

Comment: @HeikoK., you may also have to provide your own `MailServiceProvider` and [configure Laravel to use it via its Inversion of Control container](http://laravel.com/docs/extending#ioc-based-extension).

Comment: Can you provide a full code sample? The Message class is a underlying class of the MailServiceProvider. Sorry i'm a bit confused and can't get my head around it. I'm very new to Laravel... :-/

Comment: @HeikoK., I don't have a Laravel project available for testing at the moment. Unfortunately, it looks like overriding the mail functionality is somewhat involved; there is no [`Manager` class](http://laravel.com/docs/extending#managers-and-factories) for mail. As I said above, I believe you will have to provide your own `MailServiceProvider` extending the Laravel one, and maybe a `Mailer` as well. Then you can use [the IoC container](http://laravel.com/docs/extending#ioc-based-extension) to plug it into Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to accept Chris's answer as he's correct, I'm just extending on what he said. Illuminate\Mail\Message has a `subject()` method which is the one that sets the subject. It looks like this:

```
/**
 * Set the subject of the message.
 *
 * @param  string  $subject
 * @return \Illuminate\Mail\Message
 */
public function subject($subject)
{
    $this->swift->setSubject($subject);

    return $this;
}
```

If you extend it like Chris says in his answer you could extend it somewhat like this:

```
public function subject($subject)
{
    $this->swift->setSubject('[' . Config::get('app.project_name') . '] ' . $subject);

    return $this;
}
```

Assuming you have the `app.project_name` configuration directive set.